# Sending htmlcontent using java mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to send the below html content to the body of the mail. 
The content is displaying only data . No border . No background colour for table header. When I execute the the html content below seperately it displays all of these. Please help

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                builder.append("<html>");
                builder.append("<head>");
                builder.append("<style>");
                builder.append("table {");
                builder.append("width:100%;");
                builder.append("}");
                builder.append("table, th, td {");
                builder.append("border: 1px solid black;");
                builder.append("border-collapse: collapse;");
                builder.append("}");
                builder.append("th, td {");
                builder.append("padding: 5px;");
                builder.append("text-align: left;");
                builder.append("}");
                builder.append("table th    {");
                builder.append("background-color: lightblue;");
                builder.append("color: black;");
                builder.append("}");
                builder.append("</style>");
                builder.append("</head>");
                builder.append("<body>");
                builder.append("<table >");
                builder.append("<tr>");
                builder.append("<th>First Name</th>");
                builder.append("<th>Last Name</th>  ");
                builder.append("<th>Points</th>");
                builder.append("</tr>");
                builder.append("<tr>");
                builder.append("<td>Jill</td>");
                builder.append("<td>Smith</td>  ");
                builder.append("<td>50</td>");
                builder.append("</tr>");\
                builder.append("</table>");
                builder.append("</body>");
                builder.append("</html>");
                String report = builder.toString();                     
                message.setContent(report,"text/html; charset=utf-8");
               Transport.send(message);
```

Borders are not getting displayed in the mail. Is there any fine example in which a table is sent to the email body that shows all the details including colours borders perfectly .

Comment: What class is message? Is it a `MimeMessage`?

Comment: Can I suggest that you try putting the css in as an inline `style=` in the html tag and see if that works. The browsers that are incorporated into email system are in general ancient and rarely work well with `<style>` placed in the `<head>`

Comment: Message message = new MimeMessage(session); Yes message is mimemessage

Comment: Let me try the style

Comment: But I am using style already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved after i added specific css styles to the table border .

Answer (score 0):

How the message is displayed is up to the mail reader you're using.  Not every mail reader is going to render all possible html content the same way a browser would.  Often certain kinds of content will be prohibited or ignored to prevent security problems.  Sometimes the mail reader will implement only a subset of html that's sufficient to display the most common html messages.

What mail readers have you used to display your message?  What browsers are you comparing them with?

Comment: Maybe you could describe the error and the fix, for other people who might find this question?